# Entity Framework not including children in join

Tags: entity-framework

I am using inner join to return results with Entity Framework (v6.2.0) and the following code is not returning the `RouteWaypoints` children (i.e. `route.RouteWaypoints` is always null).  Interestingly, single children are loading (Customer, OriginLocation, etc), but not multiple children:

```
public List<Route> GetAllForTripWithWaypoints(int tripId)
{
    return (
        from route in GetAllBaseWithWaypoints()
        from tripTask in DbContext.TripTasks.Where(x =>
            x.TripId == tripId && x.OriginLocationId == route.OriginLocationId)
        select route
    ).ToList();
}

private IQueryable<Route> GetAllBaseWithWaypoints()
{
    return DbContext.Routes
        .Include(x => x.Customer)
        .Include(x => x.OriginLocation)
        .Include(x => x.DestinationLocation)
        .Include(x => x.RouteWaypoints.Select(y => y.Location))
        .OrderBy(x => x.OriginLocation.Name).ThenBy(x => x.DestinationLocation.Name)
        .AsQueryable();
}
```

This approach does work if I load just the Route entity, but not when I do the join.  As a reference, this does load the children successfully:

```
public Route GetByIdWithWaypoints(int id, bool validateExists = true)
{
    var route = GetAllBaseWithWaypoints().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (validateExists && route == null)
        throw new Exception("Route not found for id: " + id);

    return route;
}
```

How can I keep it working when joining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an imperfect workaround by making two calls to the db - slightly less efficient, but it solves the problem:

```
public List<Route> GetAllForTripWithWaypoints(int tripId)
{
    var routeIds = (
        from route in GetAllBase()
        from tripTask in DbContext.TripTasks.Where(x =>
            x.TripId == tripId && x.OriginLocationId == route.OriginLocationId)
        select route.Id
    ).ToList();

    return GetAllBaseWithWaypoints().Where(x => routeIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}
```